# What is the iterative Function of the following recursive function

Tags: recursion, iteration, theory

I am trying to make this recursion function be a closed form one but cannot seem to get it just right. I did get the fact that the base case should be n > 1 but got stuck after this point. I was wondering if you guys could please help.

```
public static int fi(int n){
    if(n <=1 ) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        return (int) (1 + Math.floor(n/2));
    }
}
```

This is what i have so far:

```
public static int fi(int n){
    int val = 0;
    while(n > 1){
        val +=  (int) Math.floor(n/2);
        n = (int) Math.floor(n/2);
    }
    return val;
}
```

Comment: Where does fi() call itself?  The first function doesn't look recursive.